# Why are there no automated translated subtitles?

Tags: machine-translation

This might be a rather naive question. There are programs that can automate subtitles, and also programs that can automate translations. Why, then, is there apparently no program that can automate translated subtitles? That is, the program listens to the audio, and then outputs the subtitles in whatever language desired? I get that it won't be very high-quality subtitles, but it'd still be better than nothing.

If there is such a program (I'm unable to find one), a link to that program would answer this question.

Comment: There is already very good translators today, so just using a speech to text algorithm (like whisper) to then feed a translator works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[OpenAI's Whisper](https://openai.com/research/whisper) is a widely known automatic speech recognition model that can also translate the input audio to text in the specified target language.

There are C++ implementations that can be used reasonably well without a GPU, like [whisper.cpp](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp) and [faster-whisper](https://github.com/guillaumekln/faster-whisper).

Answer (score 0):

Even watched YouTube? Try the closed captions button.

BTW, if top quality isn't a must, simply bind a transcription software with a translate and you are done.

Comment: *bind a transcription software with a translate* How does this work? Is there a guide somewhere?

Comment: Feed the video into transcription software, get the output, then use Google translate.